# New installation on MacPro not recognised

Tags: boot

I followed all installation instructions to the letter, I didn't force UEFI so I could boot normally in OSX (MacPro 3,1).

The installation (on an external USB HDD) doesn't work at all, not when holding "option" not when going to "startup disk" in the control panel and not when popping all drives except the eOS one.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It seems I've solved it.

My external was one of those ones with a small first partition for backup software and such. I reformatted with one partition and it all works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing rEFIt on your EFI partition, this is will offer you more options when it comes to booting from alternative sources.

You can install rEFIt from inside OS X.

http://refit.sourceforge.net/